# pandas long_to_wide method based on input rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am having issue deleting nulls. My input dataframe

```
name    no     city     tr1_0  tr2_0    tr3_0     tr1_1  tr2_1      tr3_1   tr1_2   tr2_2   tr3_2 
John    11     edi      boa    51        110      cof      52       220   
Rick    12     new      cof    61        100      dcu      61       750   
Mat     t1     nyc
```

my desired output

```
     name    no city  tr1  tr3  tr2   
0    John    11  edi  boa  110   51  
1    John    11  edi  cof  220   52    
2    Rick    12  new  cof  100   61   
3    Rick    12  new  dcu  750   61  
4    Matt    13  wil  nan  nan  nan
```

i used below code

```
df1 = pd.read_fwf(inputFileName, widths=widths, names=names, dtype=str, index_col=False )

feature_models = [col for col in df1.columns if re.match("tr[0-9]_[0-9]",col) is not None]

features = list(set([ re.sub("_[0-9]","",feature_model) for feature_model in feature_models]))
ub("_[0-9]","",feature_model) for feature_model in feature_models]))

df1 = pd.wide_to_long(df1,i=['name', 'no', 
df1 = pd.wide_to_long(df1,i=['name', 'no', 'city',],j='ModelID',stubnames=features,sep="_")
```

my current output as below. row 2 doesn't make any sense in my use case so i don't want to generate that row at all. if there is no trailer i only want 1 row which is good (row 6). if there are 2 trailers,i only want 2 rows but its giving me 3 rows. (row 2 and row 5 are extra). i tried using dropna but its not working. Also in my case its printing as nan not NaN.

```
     name    no city  tr1  tr3  tr2 
0    John    11  edi  boa  110   51 .  
1    John    11  edi  cof  220   52 .  
2    John    11  edi  nan  nan  nan .  
3    Rick    12  new  cof  100   61 .  
4    Rick    12  new  dcu  750   61 .  
5    Rick    12  new  nan  nan  nan .  
6    Matt    13  wil  nan  nan  nan .
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this alternative solution with [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = df1.set_index(['name', 'no', 'city'])
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df1 = df1.stack(1, dropna=False).reset_index(level=3, drop=True)

mask = df1.index.duplicated() & df1.isnull().all(axis=1)

df1 = df1[~mask].reset_index()
print (df1)
   name  no city  tr1   tr2    tr3
0  John  11  edi  boa  51.0  110.0
1  John  11  edi  cof  52.0  220.0
2  Rick  12  new  cof  61.0  100.0
3  Rick  12  new  dcu  61.0  750.0
4   Mat  t1  nyc  NaN   NaN    NaN
```

With your solution:

```
df1 = pd.wide_to_long(df1,i=['name', 'no', 'city'],j='ModelID',stubnames=features,sep="_")
```

For remove `NaN`s with duplicated `MultiIndex` values is possible use filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
#remove counting level
df1 = df1.reset_index(level=3, drop=True)
mask = df1.index.duplicated() & df1.isnull().all(axis=1)
df1 = df1[~mask].reset_index()
```

**Details**:

Check dupes by [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html):

```
print (df1.index.duplicated())
[False  True False  True False  True]
```

Then check missing values by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check all `True`s per rows:

```
print (df1.isnull().all(axis=1))
name  no  city
John  11  edi     False
          edi     False
Rick  12  new     False
          new     False
Mat   t1  nyc      True
          nyc      True
dtype: bool
```

Chain by `&` for `bitwise AND`:

```
mask = df1.index.duplicated() & df1.isnull().all(axis=1)
print (mask)
name  no  city
John  11  edi     False
          edi     False
Rick  12  new     False
          new     False
Mat   t1  nyc     False
          nyc      True
dtype: bool
```

Invert boolean mask by `~`:

```
print (~mask)
name  no  city
John  11  edi      True
          edi      True
Rick  12  new      True
          new      True
Mat   t1  nyc      True
          nyc     False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks so much. @jezdrael. I have another problem..those trailers can be dynamic meaning..i need to define 3 trailers but some times columns won't be populated in 3rd trailer..in that case

Comment: Thanks so much. @jezdrael. i tried using your split logic. I have another problem..those trailers can be dynamic meaning..i need to define 3 trailers but some times columns won't be populated in the third trailer. that case i am getting this o/p.its trating this as 1 row "2  John  11  edi  nan  nan  nan"  how can i remove thes    name  no city  tr1  tr2  tr3   
0  John  11  edi  boa   51  110 
1  John  11  edi  cof   52  220 
2  John  11  edi  nan  nan  nan
3  Rick  12  new  cof   61  100
4  Rick  12  new  dcu   61  750
5  Rick  12  new  nan  nan  nan
6  Matt  13  wil  nan  nan  nan

Comment: can some one help? Thanks

Comment: @NDommeti one idea - if check `print (df. isnull())` it return `True` for `NaN` values? if not, maybe help `df=df. replace('nan', np. nan)`