# Compare column values based on list in Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes as below:

df1:

```
ID    list     value  listA  valueA  listB   valueB
1     list1     D1    list1     D1   list1     D1
2                     list2     D1 
3     list1     D3                   list2     D3
4     list2     D1    list2     D1   list1     D3 
5     list2     D2    list2     D2   list2     D2  
6     list2     D3    list1     D3   list1     D4
```

df2:

```
list1  list2
 D1     456
 D2     D2
 33     D31 
 D4     245
 EE     D5 
 D5     D6
```

I'm trying to generate a final df based on the below validations

-> If value of list in df1 is list1, then the corresponding data of "value" in df1 should be one among the values of the list1 column in df2 3.

-> If value of list in df1 is list2, then the corresponding data of "value" in df1 should be one among the values of the list2 column in df2.

Expected Result df:

```
ID   list   value  listA  valueA  listB  valueB Error
1    list1   D1    list1     D1   list1    D1   no mismatch
2                  list2     D1                 valueA mismatch
3    list1   D3                   list2    D3   value, valueB mismatch
4    list2   D1    list2     D1   list1    D3   value,valueA&valueB mismatch
5    list2   D2    list2     D2   list2    D2   no mismatch
6    list2   D3    list1     D3   list1    D4   value, valueA mismatch
```

Comment: Why asking same question twice? [Your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422071/compare-dataframe-columns-with-conditions)

Comment: @Sociopath - Yes, I did split the question into two, as they deal with different validations, just to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with custom function with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for boolean mask and set values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m = df1.groupby('list')['value'].transform(lambda x: x.isin(df2[x.name]))
df1['Error'] = np.where(m, 'No mismatch with df2','list mismatch with df2')
print (df1)
   ID   list value                   Error
0   1  list1    D1    No mismatch with df2
1   2  list1    D2    No mismatch with df2
2   3  list1    D3  list mismatch with df2
3   4  list2    D1  list mismatch with df2
4   5  list2    D2    No mismatch with df2
5   6  list2    D3  list mismatch with df2
```

Comment: expected results are satisfied

Comment: the code throws an error when the values are made empty for any row in df1. error - "Length mismatch: Expected axis has 5 elements, new values have 6 elements". Any help with this? @jezrael

Comment: @Osceria - Problem is missing values are excluded in groupby, solution is `df2 = df2.assign(missing=np.nan)` and `m = df1['value'].groupby(df1['list'].fillna('missing')).transform(lambda x: x.isin(df2[x.name]))`

Comment: This change marks the rows with empty values as "list mismatch". Rather it should ignore the rows from validation that have empty values.- @Jezrael

Comment: @Osceria - Can you check `m1 = df1['list'].notnull()
df11 = df1[m1]

m = df11.groupby('list')['value'].transform(lambda x: x.isin(df2[x.name]))
df1.loc[m1, 'Error'] = np.where(m, 'No mismatch with df2','list mismatch with df2')` ?

Comment: It works now. However, I edited the question to add  2 more list-value columns listA, valueA & listB, valueB. In this case, what's the best way to apply the code work altogether. Is there any better approach other than iteration?

Comment: @Osceria - There should be created 2 columns dataframe, but simplist way shuld be from columns `list_1, value_1`, `list_2, value_2` with `df.columns= df.columns.split('_', expand=True)` and then `df = df.stack()`

Comment: You mean to say that the dataframe df1 should be split into three based on its columns list, listA & listB? I think I'm not getting it right. my actual dataframe df1 will have 5 different combinations of list&value columns & all these will have one value from list1 or list2 from df2

Comment: @Osceria - no, I think join together, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51580295/2901002)

Comment: that post is helpful but that way generates the output with multiple rows for the same ID and this shouldn't happen in my case whereas my expected result should have the same number of rows as the input dataframe and just one error column to mention like this "Value , ValueA, ValueB mismatch with the list". How to overcome this?

Comment: Edited the desired output dataframe - @jezrael